# Will my old pci express v2 video card (evga 8800 gt) work in a mobo with a pci express v3 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm looking to get a new motherboard. I know that if the graphics card has a higher PCI version than the slot, it should work. But what about the other way around, where the slot has a higher version than the card?

Also, do I need to be aware of power connectors? Ie will some motherboards have incompatible power connectors that won't work with my evga 8800 gt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by kobaltz, the slots are backwards compatible and will revert to PCIe2 performance.

To complete the answer to part 2 of your question:

> do I need to be aware of power connectors? Ie will some motherboards have incompatible power connectors that won't work with my evga 8800 gt?

By power connector you mean the the outlet on the back of the card, this is supplied by your PSU and not the motherboard. So as long as you are using your curent PSU and it supports your new motherboard, you would be good. So the real question would be. Will your exisitng PSU support the new motherboard? Beest to check plugs and pins of both.

[image: evga]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I have a Z77 Motherboard right now with dual PCIE3 slots running Crossfire 6970s. They are backwards compatible. However, your PCIE bus will be downgraded to PCIE2 performance and bandwidth.